# Why is the 'sample width not specified' error being thrown?

Tags: python, wave

I'm trying to write to a wav file in Python 3 using the wave module, but I get a 'sample width not specified' exception. Why is this?

```py
def write_sample(path, sample):
    """Writes a sample to a file at path location

    Arguments:
    path -- file path
    sample -- sample to be written 
    """
    with wave.open(path, 'w') as wave_file:
        # set up (make generic later)
        wave_file.setnchannels(1)
        wave_file.setsampwidth(16)
        wave_file.setframerate(44100)

        sample = struct.pack(f"<{len(sample)}h", sample)
        wave_file.writeframesraw(sample)
```

Comment: Solved, misread the .setsampwidth method as n being bits, not bytes

Comment: you could add your solution as answer and later mark it as accepted.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Solved, misread the .setsampwidth method as n being bits, not bytes